Do rotating charges emit radiation?
We all know that accelerating charges emit radiation but what about a charge rotating on it's axis like a planet?

a homogeneously charged (volume or surface) sphere rotating at a constant angular velocity has a static magnetic field but it does not radiate as a linearly accelerating charge would.

Linearly accelerated charges should emit radiation (bremsstrahlung) because something is interacting/pushing it into a non-inertial direction... Is something equivalent causing the rotating charge to rotate on its axis?

Related: Why does not a steady and divergenceless current distribution radiate?

A rotating charged ellipsoid radiates.

variations in the angular velocity could radiate waves (precession, angular acceleration etc.)

@hyportnex  Not only linearly accelerated charges but also point charges moving  on a circular path with constant angular velocity (and thus with centripetal acceleration) radiate!

Consider the homogeneous volume charge of the steadily rotating sphere as a classically limitlessly divisible substance. Then the answer is very simple. The rotating charge of the sphere can be divided into rotating charged circular loops with constant charge density, which represent stationary current loops. Each loop represents a time independent charge and loop current and the electrical and magnetic fields of a loop are static fields. Thus from this point of view there is no radiation. (See text books).
The problem is more complicated if you consider the rotating charge of the sphere as composed of small elements represented by finite point charges. It suffices again to consider the circular loop currents. Then, each rotating charge element $\Delta q$ in a steady circular loop current experiences a centripetal acceleration $a=v^2/r$ and should radiate an electromagnetic wave with a total power P proportional to the square of this acceleration $a^2$ according to Larmor's formula (valid for $v<<c$) (see Wikipedia): $$P=  \frac{\mu_0 (\Delta q)^2 a^2}{6 \pi c}$$
However, the total radiation power of a rotating loop consisting of many such discrete charge elements is not just the sum of radiation power of the discrete charge elements given by Larmor's formula. One has to consider the interference of retarded wave fields of all elements. It can be shown that for a large number of such charge elements (point charges) the total emitted power of a charged loop and thus also of a charged sphere becomes vanishingly small.
I detailed recent discussion of the solution of the steady loop current radiation problem with discrete point charges can be found here:
Kirk T. McDonald, Why Doesn’t a Steady Current Loop Radiate? 2016,
S.A. Li, A Steady Loop Current Does Not Radiate, 2023

Charged particles like electrons don't rotate on their axis when we say it has a 'spin'. The spin is merely the intrinsic angular momentum of a particle. You can calculate that a particle doesn't spin on its axis if you try to calculate its linear velocity as a function of angular velocity. This answer would give you a linear velocity >> speed of light, which is impossible. Therefore, a charged particle doesn't emit radiation until accelerated or given the energy to jump from the ground state to a higher state.
Hope this helped.

This doesn't answer the question at all! The question was not about a particle with spin, it was about a (spherical) rotating charge.

The question was about a spherical particle rotating on its axis (similar to planets rotating or 'spinning' on its axis), but particles don't behave that way. They don't rotate on their axis and if they did, their linear velocity would be much greater than the speed of light which is impossible. I talked about intrinsic spin because people tend to get confused between it and a spherical body spinning on its axis.

Read the question, it is about a rotating charge, a very classical object. The answer is not at all that trivial!

Consider a rotating sphere with constant density $\rho$ of electric charge and angular momentum $\omega$, causing a current of $\mathbf{j}(\vartheta)=\rho\omega\sin(\vartheta)\mathbf{e}_\varphi$. This setup is stationary (time-independent), hence solutions of the Maxwell equations are as well and there will be no electromagnetic radiation, which are solutions of the wave equation containing a derivative with respect to time. Electric fields inside and outside are easy to compute as well as the magnetic field outside. The magnetic field inside is a bit more laborious, but I've done it a while back. It's given by:
$$
B_r(r,\vartheta)
=\frac{1}{5}\mu_0\omega\rho\cos(\vartheta)r^2;
$$
$$
B_\vartheta(r,\vartheta)
=-\frac{2}{5}\mu_0\omega\rho\sin(\vartheta)
r^2.
$$
You can get it using the assumtion $B_\mathrm{r}\propto\cos(\vartheta)$, which comes from the magnetic flux lines leaving the northern hemisphere ($\cos(\vartheta)>0$) and again entering the southern hemispehre ($\cos(\vartheta)<0$).
